# window.open with $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, same-origin-policy

I am trying to populate the input fields from one web page with the input field values from another page. Since this violates Same Origin Policy, I have decided to try http://www.whateverorigin.org/ as a workaround solution. Here is the code:

```js
<script>
// CROSS DOMAIN JSON-P 
 $.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8", //maybe "ISO-8859-1"
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"});
 
 $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
    encodeURIComponent("https://calibercl.com/", "caliber") + '&callback=?',
    function(data) {
  
  
  var thecontents = data.contents;
  
  var username = $('#BorrFirstName').val();

  
  $('#UserName', thecontents).html(username);
  
  window.open("https://calibercl.com/", "caliber");

});
</script>
```

So to clarify, I wish for the '#BorrFirstName' field on the current page to populate the '#UserName' field on calibercl.com.

The code I have seems to work at some level because when I console.log() the #UserName it shows the innerText property set to the value from the other page. So this is good.

But now my questions is how can I get the calibercl.com web page to open and display with this value? Simply doing a window.open does not work. I suspect it has something to do with json async or the window being out of scope but I am lost.

Comment: Are you trying to build a phishing site?

Comment: I think you want `$('#UserName', thecontents).val(username)` instead of `.html()`.  A text input cannot contain html data.

Comment: Made the change and the field still comes up empty. Appreciate the response!

Comment: I have a hunch that calling window.open() needs to be done a special way